# POWERSHELL tooltip on mousehover listbox item

Tags: winforms, powershell, events, tooltip

I do a Powershell GUI, i want to use a tooltip on a listbox,
but i'm not familiar with events and event handlers, i don't find help for powershell/winform event on Microsoft.com
Below my listbox is $listbox_groupe_import

```
#Infobulle au survol pour voir les tables d'un groupe de table
$obj_infobulle = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip 
$obj_infobulle.InitialDelay = 100     
$obj_infobulle.ReshowDelay = 100 

#Sélectionne tous les groupes de tables dans la base de données et les met dans une liste déroulante 
$listbox_groupe_import = Get-ListboxGroup
#Création d'une info bulle pour la Listbox.
$obj_infobulle.SetToolTip($listBox_groupe_import, "tooltip sur listbox")
```

I want to set the tooltip on mousehover
I found this but i don't know how to execute it :

```
$listboxGroupe_MouseMove = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{
    #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    #index vaut ce qu'on pointe avec la souris au dessus de listbox1
    $index = $listBox_groupe.IndexFromPoint($_.Location)     #$_ => this (listbox.location) je crois
    ##"index ="+$index
    ##$tooltip1.SetToolTip($listBox_groupe, "index ="+$index)

    if ($index -ne -1){ 
        #Tooltype sur listbox1 = valeur de l'item pointé
        $tooltip1.SetToolTip($listBox_groupe, $listBox_groupe.Items[$index].ToString()) 
    }
    else{ 
        #on n'est pas au dessus de listBox_groupe
        $tooltip1.SetToolTip($listBox_groupe, "") 
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how to execute this code by mousehover on my listbox?
Or another way to display tooltip with different text for each item of my listbox ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you tell me how to execute this code by mousehover on my listbox?

To find the mouse location in hover event, first you can use `Control.MousePosition` to find the mouse screen location and then using `ListBox.PointToClient`, convert it to mouse position on the control. Then the rest of logic is similar to what you already have:

```
$point = $listBox.PointToClient([System.Windows.Forms.Control]::MousePosition)
$index = $listBox.IndexFromPoint($point)
if($index -ge 0) {
    $toolTip.SetToolTip($listBox, $listBox.GetItemText($listBox.Items[$index]))
}
else {
    $toolTip.SetToolTip($listBox, "")
}
```

Just to make it a bit better, I used `ListBox.GetItemText` method which is better than `ToString` method of items. In case that you set a complex object as data source of the list box and set display member property, it extracts the item text based on the display name, otherwise it returns `ToString` of the item.

Also don't forget, to handle `MouseHover` event, you need to use `Add_MouseHover`.

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly whant i want !

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
#Au survol
$listBox_groupe.add_MouseEnter({

    #récupérer la position de la souris
    $point = $listBox_groupe.PointToClient([System.Windows.Forms.Control]::MousePosition)

    #récupérer l'indice de l'item sur lequel on pointe
    $index = $listBox_groupe.IndexFromPoint($point)

    if($index -ge 0) {
        #l'infobulle est au dessus de listBox_groupe et elle a pour texte le texte de l'item
        $tooltip1.SetToolTip($listBox_groupe, $listBox_groupe.GetItemText($listBox_groupe.Items[$index]))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx).  Particularly, look at the events at the bottom.  There is a `MouseHover` event that you'll want to add:

```
$MyListBox.add_MouseHover({
    # display your tooltip here
})
$MyListBox.add_MouseLeave({
    # remove the tooltip now that user moved away
})
```

PowerShell GUIs and event handlers aren't very well documented since you usually want to handle this sort of thing in C#.

Comment: Thank you but this is an event for all the listbox, this is not what i need: i need an event for each item in this listbox

Comment: And $MyListBox.Items.Item(1).add_MouseHover{ } doesn't work

Comment: @Kishiro Then look at the documentation for `ListBoxItem`, find the proper event (it's probably the same) and apply my answer to that situation.

Comment: @Kishiro [Here's the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx). The event is called `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` or `PreviewMouseMove`

Comment: Thank you, so i tried $listBox_groupe.Items.Item(1).PreviewMouseMove({ }) and $listBox_groupe.Items.Item(1).add_PreviewMouseMove({ }) but it is written System.string don't have these methodes...

Comment: @Kishiro You're specifically accessing the element inside the listboxitem, which is indeed a string.  You need to access the listboxitem instead, not its value.  Try `$listBox_groupe.Items[1].add` instead

Comment: `$listBox_groupe.Items[1].add_MouseEnter({`  is a string too

Comment: And can i create my own event?